# React - key up event returns e.which as 0 while key down event returns correct key code

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, ios7, reactjs

For the past 2 days, I'm hell-bent on debugging an weird issue that happens only in iOS 7 devices.

I have an React Input component, for which I have added an onKeyDown and onKeyUp event handlers.

```
<input type='text' 
  defaultValue='hello' 
  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} 
  onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />

function handleKeyDown(e){
  console.log('Key down event', e.which);
}

function handleKeyUp(e){
  console.log('Key up event', e.which);
}
```

When I type in the characters, the key down event returns a proper key code but the key up event always returns 0. For example, if I press 'a', I am getting

```
Key down event 65
Key up event 0
```

I guess, because of this, the characters I type are not showing up in the textbox.

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Can you also log `e.keyCode`?

Comment: e.keyCode also returns 0.